# Triggers o Eventos en Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Necesito que se dispare un evento o trigger cada que inicie el año. Es decir que al iniciar el primer día del año se haga una inserción en la base de datos del año que acaba de empezar y de esta forma se ingresen las 24 quincenas que hay en el año tomando en cuenta los días que tiene ese año (por los años biciestos).

Comment: creo que lo más conveniente es que hagas un comando artisan con las instrucciones para insertar los datos en BD, y configures un cronjob para que lo ejecute el primer día de cada año.

Answer (score 0):

estoy trabajando con lumen-laravel, tuve la necesidad de crear un procedimiento de almacenado y un evento en la DB (en mi caso para que se ejecute a diario a las 00:00:00 horas), lo que hice fue en la migracion que crea mi tabla, hacer lo siguiente:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

Dentro de la funcion function up() que crea la tabla al final, haz esto:

DB::unprepared('tu codigo SQL...');
```

[Fuente que me ayudó](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xiKCVF9k6OA)

Answer (score -1):

Me temo que no puedes hacer ese tipo de eventos con PHP solo. Necesitas un método para ejecutar un archivo PHP que haga lo que pides.

Tienes 2 formas de hacerlos:

- Mediante una [tarea cron](https://geekytheory.com/programar-tareas-en-linux-usando-crontab), estas tareas se ejecutan con el tiempo que le indiques ejecutando lo que tu le pidas, por ejemplo, un archivo PHP.
- Mediante un [evento mysql](https://codigofacilito.com/articulos/eventos-mysql), si estas utilizando mysql, puedes programar eventos que realicen código MYSQL